# Ruby: Write escaped string to YAML

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, yaml

The following...

```
require 'yaml'
test = "I'm a b&d string"
File.open('test.yaml', 'w') do |out|
  out.write(test.to_yaml)
end
```

...outputs ...

```
--- this is a b&d string
```

How can I get it to output

```
--- 'this is a b&d string'
```

???

Comment: As I understand from the docs, that's the only way I can keep characters like the & and : (http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#single-quoted_strings).  I'm storing URLs in this yaml file that I want to be able to pull back into Ruby later intact.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to store an escaped string in YAML,
escape it using `#inspect` before you convert it to YAML:

```
irb> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb> str = %{This string's a little complicated, but it "does the job" (man, I hate scare quotes)}
=> "This string's a little complicated, but it \"does the job\" (man, I hate scare quotes)"
irb> puts str
This string's a little complicated, but it "does the job" (man, I hate scare quotes)
=> nil
irb> puts str.inspect
"This string's a little complicated, but it \"does the job\" (man, I hate scare quotes)"
=> nil
irb> puts str.to_yaml
--- This string's a little complicated, but it "does the job" (man, I hate scare quotes)
=> nil
irb> puts str.inspect.to_yaml
--- "\"This string's a little complicated, but it \\\"does the job\\\" (man, I hate scare quotes)\""
=> nil
```

YAML doesn't quote strings unless it has to.  It quotes strings if they include things that it would miss if it stored it unquoted - like surrounding quote characters or trailing or leading spaces:

```
irb> puts (str + " ").to_yaml
--- "This string's a little complicated, but it \"does the job\" (man, I hate scare quotes) "
=> nil
irb> puts %{"#{str}"}.to_yaml
--- "\"This string's a little complicated, but it \"does the job\" (man, I hate scare quotes)\""
=> nil
irb> puts (" " + str).to_yaml
--- " This string's a little complicated, but it \"does the job\" (man, I hate scare quotes)"
=> nil
```

However, as a YAML consumer, whether the string is quoted shouldn't matter to you.  You should never be parsing the YAML text yourself - leave that to the libraries.  If you *need* the string to be quoted in the YAML file, that smells bad to me.

It doesn't matter whether your strings have '&'s in them, YAML will preserve the string:

```
irb> test = "I'm a b&d string"
=> "I'm a b&d string"
irb> YAML::load(YAML::dump(test))
=> "I'm a b&d string"
irb> YAML::load(YAML::dump(test)) == test
=> true
```

Comment: For further clarification, quotes are needed only if & appears at the *beginning* of a value — and the YAML library will automatically quote the string in that case. It's never necessary to preprocess values for YAML.

Answer (score 6):

As per [YAML 1.2 Specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), JSON document is a valid YAML document.

> The primary objective of this revision is to bring YAML into compliance with JSON as an official subset.

Therefore, a valid JSON string is a valid YAML string.

```
require 'json'
'my string'.to_json  # => produces a valid YAML string
```

This is extremely usable for YAML files enriched with ERB syntax where `string.to_yaml` won't work in many cases.

Example:

```
# openvpn.yml.erb
openvpn:
  cert: <%= ENV.fetch('OPENVPN_CERT').to_json %>
  key: <%= ENV.fetch('OPENVPN_KEY').to_json %>
```

Comment: Works perfectly