# How do I declare a string with both single and double quotes in YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm internationalizing an application and cannot figure out how to declare a translation string that contains both single and double quotes. Here's an example of the en.yml string that I am trying to

```
en:
  my_string: When you're using double quotes, they look like "this"
```

With the above string, I get the following error:

```
can not load translations from /vagrant/config/locales/en.yml,
expected it to return a hash, but does not
```

If there were just double quotes, I would wrap it in single quotes and vise-versa. How do I handle both double and single quotes though?

Comment: have you tried escaping them? "When you're using double quotes, they look like \"this\""

Comment: @jvnill Sadly no, but that did the trick. I was trying to escape single quotes and it wasn't working so I assumed that doubles wouldn't escape either. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715818/ruby-write-escaped-string-to-yaml

Comment: @jvnill According to the YAML spec that should not make a difference from the plain scalar the OP is using. If it does then there is a bug in the ruby YAML implemenation.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

escaping should be done like this

```
"When you're using double quotes, they look like \"this\""
```

Comment: This... doesn't work for me. When I do something like this and then `puts` the string, it prints `When you're using double quotes, they look like \"this\"`. Help?

Comment: are you surrounding it in double quotes?

Comment: Yep. Tried single quotes as well – same result.

Comment: no it should be in double quotes. if you're using single quotes, the single quote is the one you need to escape, ie add a backslash before it. paste your entire code here or ask another question.

Comment: According to the YAML specification this quoted scalar you present as an alternative is exactly the same as the plain scalar the OP was using. This is easily verified by pasting both versions in an online parser like https://nimyaml.org/testing.html. So this is most like an actual bug in the ruby YAML implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Actually I can’t figure out why do you need obsolete typewriter quotes in translation strings. There is 2013 around and we are not stuck to ASCII-7 anymore. The typography rules dictate their demands to use [unicode quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode).

That’s the best practice ever: map those within 3rd keyboard level (or, eventually, `sed` your `yml`):

```
"When you’re using double quotes, they look like “this”"
```

With such an approach you’ll never run into troubles with escaping and your clients will definitely say “oh, neat.”

Sorry, if this seems a little bit off-topic, but since the question was about *translation strings*, I still consider it to be the best solution.

Comment: I like this idea! Just discovered I could type them with option+left/right bracket (OS X).

Comment: I know I'm late to the game with this, but using odd character for quotes doesn't make sense. They're difficult to insert, make parsing a pain (any process which ever consumes your data will need to be aware that you're using nonstandard quotes), but don't add anything. Just escape them, as in the accepted answer - there are no surprises for anyone with that method.

Comment: @Knetic You just don’t get a point. It makes a huge sense, it’s easy to insert, it makes parsing a charm (left and right quotes differ) and nobody being sane would operate on your _translated_ strings automatically on purpose. On the other hand you add an aesthetics, that has more value than everything ever. In 2015 only Neanderthals still get stuck with typewriters quotes.

Comment: I don't know in which use case I would consider this particular option but it should not be considered as a decent solution. It merely pushes the problem to others.

Comment: But a *string,* by it’s nature, shouldn’t be parsed internally. Therefore you’re not pushing the problem to others, you’re prettifying the string.

Answer (score 9):

See if this works for you, it works perfectly for me in my spring boot applications where I needed to pass JSON values in:

Using YAML pipe style:

```
app.json:
  values: |
    {"key": "value"}
```

Your case would be:

```
en:
  my_string: |
    When you're using double quotes, they look like "this"
```

Folded style might work too but I haven't tried.

See more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings