# Ansible Lineinfile - escaping single quote when using a back reference

Tags: regex, ansible, backreference

I am trying using the following Ansible play to change the default weak password for a number of SQL scripts:

```
- name: amend SQL User Passwords
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: dest=/path/to/script/{{ item.file }} state=present backup=yes
              regexp="CREATE USER (.*) PASSWORD 'password';$" line='CREATE USER \1 PASSWORD ''strongpassword'';' backrefs=yes
  with_items:
    - { file: create_db1_users_tables.sql }
    - { file: create_db2_users_tables.sql }
    - ...
    - { file: create_dbNN_users_tables.sql }
```

Though the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#single-quoted_strings) suggests that it should,

> Inside single quotes, you can represent a single quote in your string by using two single quotes next to each other.

the double single-quote are not acting as an escape character; instead they are being completely removed from the output line:

```
CREATE USER user1 PASSWORD stR0ngP@55w0rD
```

instead of

```
CREATE USER user1 PASSWORD 'stR0ngP@55w0rD'
```

So far I have tried:

1. Using double quotes - this allows the single quote around the password, however the backref is no-longer parsed, and just prints out as \1. Attempting to escape this as \\1 appears to have no affect.
2. Various different ways of escaping the single quote - backslashes, ticks. Most produce syntax errors or just output nothing.
3. Surrounding all the lineinfile arguments in double quotes (and suitably escaping everything within)
4. I can't use the Ansible database modules
5. I can't use templates, the scripts create and populate a number of tables, and can change between versions of the product - keeping templates up to date would be too much overhead.

I've found a similar Ansible question, [Quotes in ansible lineinfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126943/quotes-in-ansible-lineinfile), but the solutions did not help.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: using lineinfile (or replace) is often an antipattern; it's better to templatize the entire file (for instance). Otherwise you are simply hoping the rest of the file doesn't change, which isn't very good CM practice. Some services even support a `conf.d` syntax, which is even better.

Comment: A very good point, and one that can't be argued with. I had originally been avoiding templatising the SQL scripts because my expectation was that there would be changes between releases of the product, and I had originally been trying to write a role that would work over multiple releases. Given your point, this was the wrong approach and I've now templated the files correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I enjoy answering my own posts but having trawlled more of the internet I came across [this post](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/14bharb09y/yaml-quoting-problem#20141117qmicmdrmbwpo35civemoazntsu), where the suggestion was made to use the replace module instead of the lineinfile**. The play:

```
- name: amend SQL User Passwords
  sudo: yes
  replace: dest=/path/to/script/{{ item.file }}
           backup=yes
           regexp="^CREATE USER (.*) PASSWORD 'password';$"
           replace="CREATE USER \\1 PASSWORD 'strongpassword';"
  with_items:
    - { file: create_db1_users_tables.sql }
    - { file: create_db2_users_tables.sql }
    - ...
    - { file: create_dbNN_users_tables.sql }
```

Works as expected, generating the desired SQL.

** This also re-enforces the fact that I should spend more time reading the Ansible manuals.