# YAML syntax issue in Ansible

Tags: shell, yaml, ansible

I have the following line in Ansible script:

```
- name: get UUID    
  shell: "blkid | grep test--tgroup* | grep xfs | awk -F : '{print "blkid -s UUID -o value "$1}' |sh"
  register: UUID_value
```

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/config/test.yml': line...
May be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
    shell: "blkid | grep test--tgroup* | grep xfs | awk -F : '{print "blkid -s UUID -o value "$1}' |sh"
                                                                      ^ here
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this syntax issue?

Comment: Looks like you just need to escape your embedded quotes.

Comment: For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126943/quotes-in-ansible-lineinfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the inner doublequotes.

```
- name: get UUID    
  shell: "blkid | grep test--tgroup* | grep xfs | awk -F : '{print \"blkid -s UUID -o value \"$1}' |sh"
  register: UUID_value
```

If there wasn't the colon in your string you would have been able to just to remove the outer quotes, but that would raise another YAML error. Still, this is an option but you need to work around the colon problem like this:

```
- name: get UUID    
  shell: blkid | grep test--tgroup* | grep xfs | awk -F {{ ":" }} '{print "blkid -s UUID -o value "$1}' |sh
  register: UUID_value
```

Explanation for this colon "escaping" can be found [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890312/2753241) or [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/1341#issuecomment-25339867).

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double-quotes inside:

```
- name: get UUID    
  shell: "blkid | grep test--tgroup* | grep xfs | awk -F : '{print \"blkid -s UUID -o value \"$1}' |sh"
  register: UUID_value
```