# Coffeescript backwards double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

in this gist

https://gist.github.com/greedo/957ba26575b3f5e445dc

there is a comments.coffee file.

in that it says

```
@accessor 'quote', ->
    "“#{@get('current_comment')?.body}”"
```

The alternate type of double quotes is used.  Is that on purpose? What are those called, and what is it doing there?  Or is this just some character set conversion error.  Tried to search but i have no idea what backwards double quotes are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out @mudasobwa's answer on this question [How do I declare a string with both single and double quotes in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992328/how-do-i-declare-a-string-with-both-single-and-double-quotes-in-yaml/14992443#14992443)

The main purpose of those quotes is so that it doesn't collide with the standard double quotes if dealing with a string that needs to output one.  The coder can get away with having to remember to add a `\` if he makes sure that every string that needs a double quote uses `“` instead of `"`.

The code may be changed to the following without any effect.

```
@accessor 'quote', -> "\"#{@get('current_comment')?.body}\""
```