# Rails 5.2: apostrophe (single quote) in YAML renders as &#39; in title attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Without adding the **_html** suffix to all my YAML keys in case a foreign language should need to include a single quote / apostrophe character, how can I get such a character to render properly in a title attribute of an HTML tag?

In my case, in **fr.yml** I have:

> Report_this_comment: "Signaler ce commentaire pour violation de nos
>   conditions d'utilisation"

I am using this to render this:

```
<a href="..." title="Signaler ce commentaire pour violation de nos conditions d&#39;utilisation">Signaler</a>
```

I don't want the `&#39;` which shows up in the tooltip when I hover over the link. I just want an apostrophe.

The double-single-quote technique I have read about just gives me two `&#39;` next to each other. And prefixing it with a backslash, ie.

> Report_this_comment: "Signaler ce commentaire pour violation de nos
>   conditions d\'utilisation"

causes a server error when rendering the page.

[This SO answer from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14995220/3330613) works - it employs the curly single quote. Naturally these are a pain to work with so I was wondering whether anyone had a better current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the double quotes in **fr.yml** try this:

```
Report_this_comment: Signaler ce commentaire pour violation de nos conditions d'utilisation
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make any difference.