# syntax error in kubernetes pod.yaml running shell command

Tags: shell, docker, kubernetes-pod

Team, I have a working command but cannot figure out the syntax to run from pod.yaml. any hint?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: count_mounts
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate_command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", echo $HOSTNAME && mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '$0 <= 64  { print "Mounts are less than 64, that is found", $0 ;} $0 > 64  { print "Mounts are more than 64", $0 ;}']
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

output:

```
> here I enclosed whole command in double quotes
error: error parsing /home/pod.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: found unknown escape character

> here I left whole command as is
error: error parsing /home/pod.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: found unexpected end of stream
```

expected output:

```
node123
Mounts are less than 64, that is found 0
```

on local system without pod

```
└─ $ ▶ echo $HOSTNAME && mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '$0 <= 64  { print "Mounts are less than 64, that is found", $0 ;} $0 > 64  { print "Mounts are more than 64", $0 ;}'

node123
Mounts are less than 64, that is found 0
```

Comment: You need to quote all your args but then you're going to get nested [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992328/how-do-i-declare-a-string-with-both-single-and-double-quotes-in-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

I got around with this with below approach but would definitely like to know how to use nested quotes?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args:
      - |
        echo $HOSTNAME && mount | grep -Ec '/dev/sd.*\<csi' | awk '$0 <= 64  { print "Mounts are less than 64, that is found", $0 ;} $0 > 64  { print "Mounts are more than 64", $0 ;}'
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

resulted output:

```
kubectl logs pod/command-demo
node123
Mounts are less than 64, that is found 0
```