# Multiline strings with leading spaces

Tags: ansible

How would one specify the multiline strings that have leading spaces on some lines?

If I define a variable as

```
multiline_str: |
    foo
      bar
        baz
```

And then write it to a file using

```
- name: write multiline string
  copy: content="{{ multiline_str }}" dest="/path/to/file"
```

Then the target file contents is

```
foo
bar
baz
```

What is the trick here?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715818/ruby-write-escaped-string-to-yaml

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I don't think so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this.

```
- name: write multiline string
  copy:
    content: "{{ multiline_str }}"
    dest: /path/to/file
```

Comment: That's amazing, thanks. Why does it change the behaviour so much?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you would often have trouble with Ansible parsing quoted key=values in a single string, and you could avoid it by passing params as an YAML collection.  Thanks for providing a concise example to encourage this style of writing tasks.  You can also see [a discussion in the past](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/GfJBkzuTTNM/iUkzUKPmBnAJ) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem combined with `local_action`.

This works:

```
- name: write multiline string
  local_action:
    module: copy
    content: "{{ multiline_str }}"
    dest: /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use \n (newline) and \s (space) \t (tab)

Comment: I get `\s` also in output of `lineinfile`, i.e. doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape notation to keep the leading spaces:

```
multiline_str: |
  \  foo
  \    bar
  \      baz
```

Comment: this is visible in output if used with `lineinfile`, where is this working?!