# How to append multiline string with leading space to a remote file in host with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have the same question as in [Multiline strings with leading spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260500/multiline-strings-with-leading-spaces), but the solutions I found there don't work for the `lineinfile` module I'm currently using to **append** to an existing text file in remote host.

Idea is to write a log with bullet list, i.e. an output file like this. It's created line by line in different tasks in the play.

```
Start
 - perform X
  + perform X1
 - perform Y
End
```

I tried literally everything and guess this is possible in YAML (https://yaml-multiline.info/), but Ansible is breaking it again like it did before (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12133). Anybody aware of any workaround?

Here are two attempts I guess should work from YAML side. First one is even a syntax error for Ansible.

```yaml
- name: append log
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ log_path }}"
    line: |6
       - perform X
        + perform X1
```

```yaml
- name: append log
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ log_path }}"
    line: "\
 - perform X\n
  + perform X1\n"
```

Output in the file in the second has leading space stripped and indention doesn't match the other bullet points from single line strings:

```
Start
- perform X
 + perform X1
 - perform Y
End
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail your use case? And can you give more information what you try to achieve exactly? Currently I understand from your description that you could easily use the `copy` or `template` module and that there would be no need to use [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) as "_This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only._".

Comment: Why do you think that? I wrote that I need to **append** text to a file. How do you do this with these modules? My ansible code is self explanatory. But I even wrote that I'm writing a protocol and pasted a desired result. What do you need?

Comment: @jan: I think U880D is thinking about [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency), meaning: if you run the exact same playbook twice, what do you expect at the end: to see two task `perform X` and its subtask? Or to see it only once?

Comment: And FYI `|6` doesn't act on the rendering (you can see it on yaml-multiline.info) but on the number of indentation spaces needed based on the indentation of the key in order to be considered as part of the block.

Comment: This protocol is not idempotent. This could be achieved with the `blockinfile` module, but I prefer a non idempotent output without comment lines. I don't understand your hint regarding the indentation indicator. Count the spaces, there are exactly 7, i.e. 6 should be ignored, but 1 should really be in the output, like visible in yaml-multiline.info

Comment: @jan you are actually taking the starting point wrong. The six indent should not be from the module start (YAML have no idea this is an Ansible module after all), but from the parent's key indent. So `|6` means indent it 6 space further than the key (in your case `line`) to be considered as part of the block. Also mind that, when using that option on yaml-multiline, it indent the **example** but the **result** stays the same. So, it shows you that it is acting on the YAML format, not on the result it yields.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, but what is **example**?

Comment: On your right hand side on the site you have _YAML (with a key `example`, under it)_ => this is the snippet of YAML and then _Result_ => that is how the text in `example` would be rendered after it went through the YAML processor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me if you want to achieve [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency) or not.

In the case you want to achieve idempotency, the `lineinfile` module is not the proper one to use, as it is meant to change a single line, not multiple ones:

> - This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.
> - See the `ansible.builtin.replace` module if you want to change multiple, similar lines or check `ansible.builtin.blockinfile` if you want to insert/update/remove a block of lines in a file. For other cases, see the `ansible.builtin.copy` or ansible.builtin.template modules.

<sup>*Source: [`lineinfile` module synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#synopsis)*</sup>

---

But, as far as your indentation matter is concerned, then you could use the [`indent`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) filter of Jinja and place your desired lines in the `vars` of your module. You will also need the second parameter of the `indent` filter set to `true`, as you also want to indent the first line:

```yaml
- name: append protocol
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ protocol_path }}"
    line: "{{ _line | indent(1, true) }}"
  vars:
    _line: |
      - perform X
       + perform X1
```

This will render in:

```
 - perform X
  + perform X1
```

Comment: That looks like some overhead to get it done, but nice to see a real solution, thanks! No  idempotency is not a requirement here, but note that the `blockinfile` module has the very same issue, i.e. your solution is needed there, too.

Answer (score 1):

It is still unclear for me what you try to achieve. One point is idempotency, an other point is a mutually exclusive problem description. However,

> *I need to append text to a file. How do you do this with these modules?*

from your description and example I understand that you have a file

**Input** (`input.file`)

```
Start
 - perform Y
End
```

<sub>*Annot.: A protocol or an algorithm*</sub>

in which you like to insert lines before and expect a result like

**Output / Result** (`output.file`)

```
Start
 - perform X
  + perform X1
 - perform Y
End
```

<sub>*Annot.: Insert before performing `Y` because of the given examples. Not to append in any case as it looks like for me that `Start` and `End` are markers within the file and part of the protocol. Furthermore an algorithm or protocol depends on order otherwise it would be a log file.*</sub>

---

One option for processing could be to patch the file.

```bash
diff input.file output.file > input.diff
cat input.diff
1a2,3
>  - perform X
>   + perform X1
```

**Processing**

So an example playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Apply patch to a file
    patch:
      src: input.diff
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test/output.file"
```

will result into the necessary output.

---

> "*It is created in the play at different stages line by line. In one situation I would like to add a multiline string in one append operation.*"

If you like to write a protocol about what happened, also know as log file and to append [raw strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings) to an existing (log) file you may have a look into the following approach with as `!unsafe` marked strings

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Append (unsafe) lines to log
    lineinfile:
      path: log.file
      create: true
      line: !unsafe >-
        test
          - test
           + test
```

resulting into a file with a content of

```bash
cat log.file
test
  - test
   + test
test
  - test
   + test
test
  - test
   + test
```

after three (3) iterations.

> *Ansible uses a data type called `unsafe` to block templating. ... The Ansible implementation ensures that unsafe values are never templated.*

This will not only give the possibility to have leading whitespace(s) but also allow special characters like `{` or `%`.

Comment: Ah that's your misunderstanding. That is not an input file, but the desired output file. It is created in the play at different stages line by line. In one situation I would like to add a multiline string in one append operation. See my own answer with my current workaround.

Comment: ... it is sometimes just not clear how to interpret words without contextual description since `protocol (formal record of observations) != protocol (set of rules)`. In computing it is mostly interpreted as set of rules. In an other context it could also be related to diplomatic and governing affairs and which I think don't apply here. But that's more a discussion for https://english.stackexchange.com/ and why I've asked for more context.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, sorry. I meant log or audit trail, the German word Protokol is more general as the English protocol I guess. Thanks for the link to the `!unsafe` syntax, didn't know that one!

Answer (score 0):

I found one workaround that uses single line strings and a loop, i.e. I document it here, but would still prefer to have a solution for the general real multiline case (e.g. from a variable):

```
- name: append protocol
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ protocol_path }}"
    line: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - " - perform X"
    - "  + perform X1"
```