# Ansible not honoring blockinfile indent value

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible blockinfile with its indent feature. Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Add line to netplan file
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml.REMOVE
    marker: ""
    block: |4
          test
```

Here is the 00-installer-config.yaml.REMOVE file before the change:

```
test
```

Here is it after

```
test
  test
```

Notice how it only does 2 spaces, even though I state clearly to use 4. I have tried 8 spaces, and 10, any integer. Always indents 2 spaces. why?

Comment: Linked comment on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74782152/how-to-append-multiline-string-with-leading-space-to-a-remote-file-in-host-with/74783504#comment131981346_74782152

Answer (score 1):

The simple playbook below writes the block into the file

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test: |
      test
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: "{{ test }}"
```

The text is not indented in the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
test
```

If we indent the text in the block further

```yaml
  vars:
    test: |
        test
```

the text is still not indented in the file because YAML interprets all four spaces as YAML indentation

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
test
```

If we tell YAML that we will use only two spaces as YAML indentation

```yaml
  vars:
    test: |2
        test
```

The text will be indented by 2 spaces because YAML takes 2 spaces as YAML indentation and the next 2 spaces as part of the text in the block

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
  test
```

This explains the behavior of the text indentation in a block.

---

Notes:

- Optionally, you can use Jinja filter [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test: |
      line1
      line2
      line3
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: |
          {{ test|indent(4, first=true) }}
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
    line1
    line2
    line3
```

- See [Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control)
- See [Block Style Productions](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-8-block-style-productions)